# Trying to get session data, works from one route does not work from other

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, session-variables

I am trying to get session data, using passport js. When I use the /test or /test2 route, I get the session data. If I try to console.log in these routes, I get the whole session data. But when I try it with /user_data, I dont seem to get the expected response. Where am I going wrong here? I am using passport.js and express session. When going through the /user_data route, I get the following output:

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```

Here is the code I am using, it is fairly dirty as of now as I am trying to tinker around.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session');
const port = 3000
const passport =require("passport")
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth2').Strategy;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID:"some.com",
        clientSecret:"some_secret",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
        passReqToCallback   : true
    },
    function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            return done(null, profile);
    }
));
app.use(session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'SECRET' 
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/failed", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Failed")
})
app.get("/success", (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Welcome ${req.user.email}`)
})

app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
            scope:
                ['email', 'profile']
        }
    ));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        failureRedirect: '/failed',
    }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/')

    }
);
app.get("/test",(req,res)=>{
    let sess = req.session;
    console.log(sess);
    var email=sess.passport.user.email;
    var netid=email.split('@')[0];
    req.session.netid=netid;
    console.log(netid);
    // console.log(sess.user.id);
    res.send("test")
});
app.get("/test2",(req,res)=>{
    let sess = req.session;
    console.log(sess);
    var netid=sess.netid;
    console.log(netid);
    res.send("test2")
});
app.get("/user_data",(req,res)=>{
    var sess = req.session;
    console.log(sess.passport);
    res.send(sess.passport);
});
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){req.logOut();res.redirect('/');});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pages/index.html");})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory user_data is just another endpoint and on that basis it should work just like test and test2.

However, user_data could be a reserved name. Try changing that endpoint to something else.

Comment: sess, sess.passport, nothing works. ideally after login is done, i should access all of session data, but i only get the above mentioned output when i try with /user_data , but i get the expected response in /test. pardon me for the late response.

Comment: What happens if you rename user_data to something else, e.g. experiment?

Comment: it works if I change the name, that does not make sense

Comment: user_data could be a reserved name

Comment: oh okay, fair enough , much thank

Comment: I changed my answer, please accept if that solved the issue.